# Order posts by modification date in Wordpress Categories

Tags: wordpress

I just need a code to order posts in category page by last modification date.
Examples: http://windows10top.com/

I found this code and it works great in homepage

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=modified&order=desc'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Need it to work also by for specific categories.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  $args = array(
      'orderby' => 'modified',
      'order'=> 'DESC'
  );
  query_posts($args);
```